# Angular 8 ng-reflect-model shows correct date value but not reflecting in input

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Using

```
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12">
  <input
    id="licenseForEdit.issuedDate"
    type="date"
    name="licenseForEdit.issuedDate"
    pInputText
    placeholder="License Issued Date"
    [(ngModel)]="licenseForEdit.issuedDate"
    required
    [class.field-error]="form.submitted && !licenseForEdit.issuedDate"
  />
</div>
```

I get:

```
<input _ngcontent-atp-c10="" id="licenseForEdit.issuedDate" name="licenseForEdit.issuedDate" pinputtext="" placeholder="License Issued Date" required="" type="date" ng-reflect-required="" ng-reflect-name="licenseForEdit.issuedDate" ng-reflect-model="2019-01-01T00:00:00" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
```

Yet, the input field remains: [image: DatePattern]
**How do I get the Model's value to display in the input box? I suspect that it's a databinding issue, but...**

Comment: The issue is apparently the two-way binding:
    **[ngModel]="licenseForEdit.issuedDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'"**

Comment: I REALLY need the two-way binding. Anyone know HOW to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First please check if the format is correct.

Find the reference for MDN here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date.

In case the value needs to be transformed for display purpose please use pipe.

https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: abhay, thanks for answering; license.issuedDate is a date-typed typescript field being two-way bound (banana-box syntax); thus, pipes are not an option... I wish it were that easy... :-)

Comment: There is also one more method where in you use a pipe to display a different format but which submitting data you can reformat it.
One another way which we are doing is having a data attr and updating both value and data attr upon change.

Comment: In my case, I was using moment and formatting it to DD/MM/YYYY whereas the MDN link indicated it needs setting in YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 0):

The date doesn't show into your input, because for inputs of type="date" you need to format it to "YYYY-MM-DD". For this you can use **moment.js**:

1. Install moment in your client app by command `npm install moment --save`
2. Add import statement in top of your component like
   this: `import * as moment from 'moment'`

You can use moment in your code:

```
let formatedDate = moment(dateToBeFormated).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```